# Sending screenshot via C#

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm saving by capturing screenshot via that code.

```
Graphics Grf;
Bitmap Ekran = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Grf = Graphics.FromImage(Ekran);
Grf.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
Ekran.Save("screen.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Then send this saved screenshot as e-mail:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(kime);
if (dosya != null)
{
   Attachment eklenecekdosya = new Attachment(dosya);
   msg.Attachments.Add(eklenecekdosya);
}
msg.From = new MailAddress("aaaaa@xxxx.com", "Konu");
msg.Subject = konu;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = mesaj;
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
NetworkCredential guvenlikKarti = new  NetworkCredential("bbbb@bbbb.com", "*****");
client.Credentials = guvenlikKarti;
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.live.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

I want to do this : How can I send a screenshot directly as e-mail via smtp protocol without saving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the Bitmap to a Stream.  Then attach the Stream to your mail message.  Example:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
Ekran.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
stream.Position = 0;
// later:
Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream, "MyImage.jpg");
```

Comment: Remember to surround these calls with a using block so that you don't have memory leaks, or call the .Dispose() methods to free the memory.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my answer and when I finally posted it I saw your is the same. Do you prefer me to delete mine? :) Anyway, +1 for you

Comment: Yes - Digicoder raises an important point.  The original code could be improved by using "using" blocks over all IDisposable objects.  I left it out for simplicity, and also because properly setting up "using" blocks would require revising all the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Ekran.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    using (Attachment att = new Attachment(ms, "attach_name"))
    {
        ....
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```