# Attach an image to mail

Tags: c#, image, email, screenshot

I made a little application that captures the screen using this code:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty,Point.Empty,Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size);
```

Now i want to attach the screenshot to a mail. I already wrote the neccesary code for sending the mail and all I want is to attach the image. Here is the code that I used for the mail:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("mail_address@gmail.com");
        message.Subject = "Subject";
        message.Body = "Body";
        message.To.Add("mail_address@gmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail_address@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2825950/1443529. You could use `Attachment` with constructor accepting `Attachment(Stream, ContentType)`

Comment: Yes for inline attachments you can have a look at @JeremyThompson 's reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check answer given below.You need to attach image as an attachment. Hope it helps.

```
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("mail_address@gmail.com");
    message.Subject = "Subject";
    message.Body = "Body";
    message.To.Add("mail_address@gmail.com");
    string filepath = "C:\image.jpg";     // Image File Path 
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filepath)); 

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail_address@gmail.com", "password");
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(message);
```

Comment: I know how to attach an image using its path, but this is different. I want to attach and send the image without saving it on the computer. I want to attach it directly from the variable "b". Anyway, I found the solution and I will post it here.

Comment: Here is the soultion that I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529968/sending-screenshot-via-c-sharp . It is exactly what I asked.